# How to remove image output using a counter in the range

Tags: php

Now the output of the images is carried out using a counter in 3 intervals:

```
0-73
73-88
88-141
```

Question: How to remove image output using a counter in the range 0-73?

```
$name = glob('./album/*.{php}', GLOB_BRACE);

$counter = 0; //заводим счетчик
for($i=0; $i<=(sizeof($name)-1); $i++) {
    if( substr($name[$i][2],0,1) != "_") {
        echo "<li><img src='".$dir."img/_share/".$shortname."_1.jpg' height='162px'></li>";

        $counter++;
        if ($counter == 73) {
            echo "<li><img src='".$dir."img/_share/".$shortname."_1.jpg' height='162px'></li>";
        } elseif ($counter == 88) {
            require_once "ddd.php";
        } elseif ($counter == 141) {
            break;     
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `==` comparison operator to `>` otherwise it will only execute when `$counter` is `73`. Make sure to remove the extra code that displays the image throughout the loop.

```
$name = glob('./album/*.{php}', GLOB_BRACE);

$counter = 0; //заводим счетчик
for($i=0; $i<=(sizeof($name)-1); $i++) {
 if( substr($name[$i][2],0,1) != "_") {
    //echo "<li><img src='".$dir."img/_share/".$shortname."_1.jpg' height='162px'></li>";

    $counter++;
    if ($counter > 73 && $counter <= 88) {
        echo "<li><img src='".$dir."img/_share/".$shortname."_1.jpg' height='162px'></li>";
    } elseif ($counter > 88 && $counter <= 141) {
        require_once "ddd.php";
    } elseif ($counter > 141) {
        break;     
    } 
  }
}
```